# Maclaurin Series of cos(x)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Using the Maclaurin Series of cos(x) ${\displaystyle \cos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\quad\textrm{for }|x|<\infty.$ Consider $\displaystyle f(x)=x^2\cos\big(\dfrac{x^2}{2} \big)$ find the value of $f^{(10)}(0)$. My guess was to expand out the series to obtain the new Maclaurin series form of f(x) and then find the coefficient of the 10th term.
I was able to expand out the series to obtain $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2+4n}}{2^{2n}(2n)!}$$ but am  unsure of how to proceed further.

Comment: How many terms will be non-zero in $f^{(10)}(0)$? Hint: what is the $p$-th derivative of $x^n$?

Comment: $(-1)^n\frac{1}{2^{2n}(2n)!}=f^{(2+4n)}(0)/(2+4n)!$ Put $n=2$

Comment: thanks for the reply, I see what you mean with the non zero terms with only every 4th (e.g f2, f6 f10) power having a non zero term. I derived the first 4 derivatives but am struggling to see a pattern with each derivative, is it linked to the maclaurin series of cos(x)?